# Performance Issue on Update Entity which creates records on another Entity which is joined as OneToMany

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity as

```
    @Entity
    @DynamicUpdate
    @Table(name = "document")
    class Document extends Serializable{

      @Id
      var id: UUID = _

      .
      .
      .

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
      var elements: util.List[Element] = _

      .
      .
    }
```

the Element Entity has the bidirectional mapping

```
    @Entity
    @DynamicUpdate
    @Table(name = "element")
    class Element extends Serializable{

      @Id
      var id: UUID = _

      .
      .
      .

      @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
      @ManyToOne(cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      var document: Document = _

      .
      .
    }
```

When I do a `documentRepository.save(document)` without elements, the operation goes through quickly. But when I assign a list of 10000 elements to the document after that and do the same operation again, the update is taking around 15 mins. I am looking for a way to improve the performance here. The Backend DB we are using is Postgres. Thanks!